# Function pointers: is the simple canonical use bad from a performance point of view? If so what are the c++11-ish alternatives?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm using function pointers a lot in my `c++` code, always in a way conforming to this simple canonical example (e.g. the functions have the same I/O, but the desired operation is only known at run time):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int add(int first, int second){
    return first + second;
}
int subtract(int first, int second){
    return first - second;
}
int operation(int first, int second, int (*functocall)(int, int)){
    return (*functocall)(first, second);
}
int main(){
    int  a, b;
    int  (*plus)(int, int) = add;
    int (*minus)(int, int) = subtract;
 
    a = operation(7, 5, plus);
    b = operation(20, a, minus);
    cout << "a = " << a << " and b = " << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I started using this a while ago simply because I found it simpler to use.
As I learn c++ better, I find myself wondering: is this construct, in this context, bad from a **performance** point of view? If so why and what is the better `c++11`-ish alternatives?

I couldn't find precise guidelines for this simple usage case, from a performance point of view (though plenty of guidelines for more complicated cases)

## EDIT:

Im implicitly assuming run of the mill x86 hardware.

Comment: Very loosely speaking, techniques that have been around for a while have generally been optimised for performance. That applies to function pointers. It will be no slower then calling the function explicitly.

Comment: Performance would depend a lot on the optimizations done by the C++ compiler. I would suggest to benchmark (against something using C++11 closures i.e. lambdas).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I never learned an alternative construct, so it is hard for me to benchmark. This is the main reason Im asking actually.

Comment: Lambdas, functors, and polymorphism are three other ways.

Comment: Does the parameters known at compile time ?

Comment: What about `std::function`?

Comment: @Jarod42; no, they are not known at compile time.

Comment: Then read some good [C++11 tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-1-introduction-to-c11/). You need to learn those new [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) features

Comment: Check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991424/advantage-disadvantage-of-function-pointers

Comment: @Caramiriel: Starting from the assumption that the basis for using function pointers in the first place is to improve performance, why would you use `std::function`?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That depends a lot on the compiler and the hardware.  There is hardware where an indirect call can be very expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to profile of course, but generally speaking the performance difficulty with calling through function pointers is that the compiler can't give you the benefits of inlining. Something like this might be faster:

```
enum FuncTodo{
    PLUS,
    MINUS,
};

int operation(int first, int second, FuncTodo todo) {
    switch(todo) {
        case PLUS: return first + second;
        case MINUS: return first - second;
    }
}
```

Of course this might not be possible in your usage (if you want to extend the code by adding new operations after the function `operation` is written and complied), and even if it is possible you might well consider it less maintainable.

Finally, be careful when you do profile. In your example, the compiler in principle can work out the actual destination of every call (you call `operation` with `plus`, but the compiler could "know" that the value of `plus` is really `add`). So your instructive examples might optimize better than real code in which the function pointer passed to `operation` isn't decided until runtime.

Comment: Another performance related thing is that on *some* processors, the *indirect* call required for function pointer might be slow. This is less true on recent Intel or AMD desktop or laptop processors.

Comment: @Steve: thanks I actually like this construct for its simplicity (and together with Bathsheba's comment I now worry less about performance loss) . I will try to use it more in the future. Also thanks for your last paragraph (my typical functions are more complicated than 'add' but it's good to keep your caveat in mind, specially because my question is very general)

Comment: even if the switch cases call a function, this will be faster as the compiler will inline the call. I believe it does this for all small functions (though your compiler may differ). So you don't have to inline the code manually like the answer describes (though, in this case, it hardly seems much bother)

Comment: Modern compilers aren't super great at optimizing many `switch` blocks, but I like this technique combined with template instantiation in the cases for operations that aren't quite as simple as just adding and subtracting stuff.

Answer (score 5):

If you are really worried about performance, you should consider doing compile-time dispatch - templatize operation; This will certainly work for your simple example; not sure if your real use needs true run-time operation binding (in which case this solution doesn't work).

```
    template <typename Functor>
    int operation(int first, int second, Functor f)
    {
        return f(first, second);
    }

    ...

    a = operation(7, 5, std::plus<int> /* since C++14, roll your own otherwise */);
    b = operation(20, a, std::minus<int>);
```

The performance overhead of calling through function pointers is certainly not negligible, especially for functions as short as add() and subtract(); That's the reason why the C++ std::sort  beats the pants off of C's qsort routine for simple basic types.

Answer (score 2):

Often when using function pointers or jump tables it is because we need runtime selection of a function to call, but we can't use templates and we don't want to pay the performance penalty of (runtime) polymorphism.  In those narrow situations, this is about as good as you're going to get as far as performance is concerned.  At least on x86 hardware.

It's not as easy to maintain and extend as more idiomatic techniques*, however, so unless you have an actual demonstrated need for the performance improvement offered by using function pointers and jump tables, you'd be much better off using polymorphism, templates, C++11 `function`s and lambdas, or maybe even a switch.

Bottom line, profile your code first, before you write a jump table.

---

* "More idiomatic techniques" : In some domains (like mine), jump tables are idiomatic and are very easy to maintain.  YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use compile time mechanisms to remove the runtime evaluation of a function (i.e.: you need a function pointer) you might as well have a look at speculative devirtualization.

A brief introduction called Compiler confidential from a Visual Studio Compiler Developer can be found at [channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Compiler-Confidential).

A more object oriented version of you code would look like this:

```
struct Operation {
    virtual int op(int first, int secont) = 0;
    virtual ~Operation() = default;
};


struct Add : public Operation {
    virtual int op(int first,  int second) {
        return first + second;
    }
    virtual ~Add() {}
};

struct Sub : public Operation {
    virtual int op(int first,  int second) {
        return first - second;
    }
    virtual ~Sub() {}
};

struct Mul: public Operation {
    virtual int op(int first,  int second) {
        return first * second;
    }
    virtual ~Mul() {}
};

int main () {
    std::unique_ptr<Operation> o = new Add;
    auto a = o(10,20);
}
```

depending on how much the compiler is able to optimize this down to one of the following things:

```
int main () {
    std::unique_ptr<Operation> o = new Add;
    auto a = o(10,20);
}


int main() {
    // compiler is able to prove that it will always be the Add function.
    std::unique_ptr<Add> add = new Add;
    auto a = add(10,20);
}

int main() {
    // compiler is able to prove that the scope  of add will never leave
    // main.
    Add add;
    auto a = add(10,20);
}

int main() {
    // compiler can show that inlining is faster.
    Add add;
    auto a = 10 + 20
}
```

Most likely though it will generate something like this:

```
int main() {
    // using profile guided optimization he might figure that the two most
    // frequent calls are to Add or Sub

    Operator *op; // is something unknown

    int a;
    if (typeid(op) == typeid(Add)) {
        a = 10 + 20;
    }
    else if (typeid(op) == typeid(Sub)) {
        a = 10 - 20;
    }
    else {
        a = op(10,20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various threaded code techniques, if you're looking at performance (not readability, maintainability, etc), you should read this http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/threaded-code.html about Forth and try some.